# Can I copy query tables (and connections?) to other workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook (wkbk1) that has a sheet with eight different query tables (a.k.a. data tables) on it -- NOT PIVOT TABLES.  They all point to the same external Excel workbook (wkbk2) for their data which is a single sheet with a group of named ranges.

The data for each table in wkbk1 comes from a named range in wkbk2. How can I copy the sheet of eight different tables (from wkbk1) to other workbooks (wkbk3, wkbk4, etc)?

Is it even possible for the query table and its data connection to transfer with the sheet?  So far I can't do it manually (no coding). If coding is required I'm fine with that, just need help with it. I have intermediate VBA coding experience.

I'm using Excel 2007/2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Excel 2010, I right click on the sheet tab and choose Move or Copy.  Select the destination workbook and check "Create a Copy".  The new sheet has the QueryTable on it and refreshes as expected.

So I think copying the sheet will copy the QueryTable and all its properties.

My QueryTable used MSQuery and pointed to another Excel workbook.

Comment: Dick, you answered too quickly! I was going to delete this post as it now works. I easily spent a couple hours pulling my hair out trying to get this to work.  After this morning's post I tried it again - Excel threw a fatal error! I told it to send the error info to Microsoft and restart Excel. When the workbooks came back repaired I tried it again and it worked! I really don't know what happened but now the simple copy works (like you suggested) but I swear on a stack of John Walkenbach tutorials I couldn't get it to work earlier!  Oiy!